# Bootstrap toggle chevron

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and I have some collapsible panels which act as filters on a results page. So it isnt really an accordion menu as more than one can be open at any given time. Plus some will be open upon page load (using class in). So I need some javascript that will toggle the chevron depending on the state of the panel (opened or closed).

Here is the mark up:

```
                <!-- Filter options -->
            <div id="accordion">
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h5><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Subject<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a></h5>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li class="selected"><a href="#"><span class="uxf-icon uxf-close-square"></span></a>Foreign Relations (15676) </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Vietnam War (13013)</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Government Documents (10479)</a> </li>
                            <li class="selected"><a href="#"><span class="uxf-icon uxf-close-square"></span></a>Military Assistance</li>
                            <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h5><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Geography<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a></h5>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">  
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><a href="#">Foreign Relations (15676)</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Vietnam War (13013)</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Government Documents (10479)</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Military Assistance </a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
                        </ul>    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-header">
                    <h5><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Person As Subject<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a></h5>
                    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">    
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><a href="#">Foreign Relations (15676)</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Vietnam War (13013)</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Government Documents (10479)</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Military Assistance </a>
                            </li><li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
                        </ul>  
                    </div>   
                </div>     
            </div>
```

Obviously at the minute all of the panels have the chevron down icon.
Many thanks

Comment: So...what have you tried so far ? Plus, if I'm not mistaken, Bootstrap [already has](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) a JavaScript `collapse` that goes along with events etc..

Comment: you want something like plus to open and minus to close on div right? or you want accordian?

Comment: check this http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion it also require angularjs (http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, I want more of a plus/minus thing. Not an accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the open/closed status of each div by looking for the `in` class. 
Once set you can swap the chevron classes within a click event.

```
// onload
$('a[data-toggle=collapse]').each(function() { 
    var chevron = $(this).parent().next('div');
    if ( chevron.hasClass('in') ) {
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    } else {
        $(this).children('span').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
});

// click event
$('a[data-toggle=collapse]').click( function() {  
    // swap chevron
    $(this).children('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CL2d1Ht34k)